# PostgreSQL Installation on Big Sur Failure

Tags: postgresql, macos, installation, pgadmin

I have upgraded my Mac to Big Sur 11.1 and am trying to install PostgreSQL from EnterpriseDB, but I keep running into two errors before the installation completes.

The errors are as follow:

1. A non-fatal error occur whilst creating menu shortcuts.
2. problem running post-install step. installation may not complete correctly the database cluster

After these errors occur, the window tells me the installation has been completed but Admin4 takes a long time to open and open on Google Chrome and the 'data' folder has no content.

Can someone help me resolve these issues while installing PostgreSQL from EnterpriseDB?

Comment: I’m running into the same issue. Did you find a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into a similar problem after update to Big Sur and upgrade of PostgreSQL (non-EnterpriseDB version though) to newer version.

It worked after I granted postgres components all available permissions under Security & Privacy (Full Disk Access and Automation) and reinstall.

[Screenshot from preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxiDW.png)